# How to get index of an array element in click event with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm developing an Electron App, and for this specific part of the code, it's necessary that I recover the index of the current element (on click).

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="optionBox"> Minimize to tray after 10 seconds
    <input type="checkbox" class="optionBox"> Always check day transition
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
modifierCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.optionBox');

for (var i = 0; i < modifierCheckboxes.length; i++) {
    modifierCheckboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        bindModifierCheckBoxes(e);
    });
}

function bindModifierCheckBoxes(e) {
    // I need the reference for modifierCheckboxes[i] here 
}
```

I've tried this:

```
function bindModifierCheckBoxes(e){
    var t=e.target;
    console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(t.parentNode.childNodes,t));
}
```

It came "close", but when I click on the first checkbox, I get index of 1, and in the second one I get 3.

Please, no external libraries, just plain JavaScript.

Comment: BTW, `[].indexOf` is a shorter version of `Array.prototype.indexOf`

Comment: @JohnHascall my advice would be to stay away from `.indexOf` because it is **not** cross-browswer compatible.  There are other, safer JavaScript methods to check for string literals, etc. `.match()` and `.test()` respectively acheives what `.indexOf()` does and is cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Yes, IE<9 is stupid.  If you have to care, you have my pity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can convert the Object selector to an array and then you can use an indexOf.

```
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.optionBox');

checks.forEach(function(check){
  check.addEventListener('click', checkIndex);
})

function checkIndex(event){
  console.log( Array.from(checks).indexOf(event.target) );
}
```

Comment: But you didn't need to complicate it that much. Here I got the same result using your method but in a much simpler way:
`modifierCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.optionBox');
modifierCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    console.log( Array.from(plusBtns).indexOf(e.target) )
//...etc
    });
}`@Codes

Answer (score 4):

Make use of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
modifierCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.optionBox');

modifierCheckboxes.forEach(function(checkbox, i) {
    checkbox.checked = customConf[i];;
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        bindModifierCheckBoxes(e, i);
    });
});

function bindModifierCheckBoxes(e, index) {
    // index is passed inside the event listener function
}
```

Comment: Clever! Only thing, you may have to use i + 1 inside the listener or use index +1 inside the Modifier function.

Comment: @Amir I think he wants it like that so he can access an array (probably `customConf` again). Plus it's clear. He can adapt it to his need.

Comment: I've tried that too, but the variable i always gets caught with the value 2, and pass modifierCheckboxes[i] didn't help either

Comment: @RickStanley you were right. `for` ruins the closure as it continue to modify `i` which whenever `bindModifierCheckBoxes` get executed it will fetch in the scope it was defined in only to find that `i` is now equal to the length of the array. But `forEach` fix that as it will create an `i` for each checkbox (separate scopes) so now it works.

Answer (score 2):

use `.children` instead of `.childNodes` ... `.children` gives a list of child Elements excluding text nodes

in HTML, when you nicely format your source, there's text nodes between `>` and `<` that don't (usually) effect the rendering of the page

Answer (score 1):

```
function bindModifierCheckBoxes(e) {
    var t=e.target;
    var checkboxes = t.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('optionBox');
    console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(checkboxes, t) + 1);
}
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7p3gsy75/

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to give your checkboxes id's (here I chose lame ones):

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="optionBox"> Minimize to tray after 10 seconds
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" class="optionBox"> Always check day transition
</div>
```

and then look at `e.target.id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` instead of `click`:

```js
$('.optionBox').on('change', function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert($(this).index());
        } else {
            alert("unchecked");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="optionBox"> Minimize to tray after 10 seconds
      <input type="checkbox" class="optionBox"> Always check day transition
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass modifierCheckboxed[i] to your  bindModifierCheckBoxes function.
So you send the référence of the current checkbox then you can do what you want with it.